# WAMP with remote DB

Tags: vpn, php, openvpn, wamp

I want to use WAMP server with a database located on another place. I can access it through a VPN (openVPN). I will change the `config.ini` of my PHP code to use the remote database (`10.x.x.x` instead of `192.168.x.x`) with the rights creditentials.

Is it the only thing to change or should I change something else ?

I can not test it right now because the DB is not hosted yet. But I have to know the answer before because this must work (nearly) immediatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the host where the DB is located should be enough. However, it seems that your database will be hosted on a remote site, so bear in mind the following:

- Firewall must be checked on the remote site to allow your VPN connection to connect to the port where your database server will run.
- If it is hosted, check if the provider allows external connections to databases (usually if you have a VPS or similar you shouldn't have any trouble, but if you just hire the hosting they might establish restrictions).
- If you're going to configure the server yourself, make sure it listens to the VPN interface too, as for example, MySQL in its default configuration only listens to the loopback interface.

This should be enough to run it, however, you can always check connectivity manually prior to make the change.